# python module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'

Tags: python, serialization, serial-port

I get this traceback when attempting to connect to a serial port on ubuntu 16.04

```
File "debugRead2.py", line 6, in <module>
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'
```

My file is named `debugRead2.py` so it isn't an issue with naming.

When I change:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)
```

to

```
from serial import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debugRead2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from serial import serial
ImportError: cannot import name 'serial'
```

I have both the `serial` and `pyserial` packages installed.

Comment: did you install using `pip` ?

Comment: yes i used pip to install

Comment: Try uninstalling the `serial` package. That one is for serializing JSON/YAML/XML, not using serial ports. It might be causing a conflict.

Comment: Open the Python interpreter from the same folder your code is in and type `import serial; serial`! What's the output?

Comment: just did, am still getting the same error

Comment: You probably need to change it to `from serial import Serial; ser = Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)`

Comment: when i type 'import serial;' serial I get '<module 'serial' (namespace)>'

Comment: When I change it to `from serial import Serial; ser = Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)` I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'Serial'` @SudheeshSinganamalla

Comment: That should usually print the filename of the module. Try `import serial; print(serial.__file__)` instead.

Comment: `>>> import serial; print(serial.Serial)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'` @KlausD.

Comment: That's not the command I gave you.

Comment: I am wondering if you installed the right `serial` library. Did you install `serial` or `pyserial` ? This issue occurs because the right library you're looking for is `pyserial`

Comment: I installed both the serial and pyserial library, but uninstalled the serial library @SudheeshSinganamalla

Comment: `import serial; print(serial.__file__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute '__file__'` @KlausD.

Comment: This question should never have been closed as a duplicate of the other, because the cause is fundamentally different. Instead, the answers about installing `pyserial` rather than `serial` should have gone here.