# 'serial' has no attribute Serial Error, not filename or import method

Tags: python

I have looked for similar solutions here however the only ones I can find do not fix the problem, and the solutions like this one [python module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial' [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47384676/python-module-serial-has-no-attribute-serial) does not get solved.

This code

```
self.ser = serial.Serial(port=self.dev_path, baudrate=600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None)
```

is giving the error

```
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'
```

I am importing serial as

```
import serial
```

However other solutions suggest using

```
from serial import Serial
```

it gives the error

```
NameError: name 'serial' is not defined
```

Edit Full Code:

```
def __init__(self, debugging=False):
    # self.ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0',baudrate=600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None)
    self.ser = serial.Serial(port=self.dev_path, baudrate=600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None)
    print(str(self.ser.name))
    self.status()
    self.debug = debugging
    if (self.debug):
        print(self.ser.name)
        print("Pulse: " + str(self.pulse) + "\n")


def __del__(self):
    self.ser.close()
```

Comment: Do you have serial installed?

Comment: Do you have any other variable named `serial`? Perhaps the instance of your class?

Comment: If nothing works, open the python command line interpreter, enter `import serial`, then `print(serial)` and `serial.` and start the autocompletion with tab to see what `serial` is in your context.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a [mcve] instead of separate, incomplete snippets. Anyhow, start Python interactively, `import serial` and then do `dir(serial)`. That should show you what the serial module contains. BTW: If you have a file `serial.py` in your current directory, you will import that instead of the system-wide one.

Comment: By the way, the `NameError` you provided indicates, that the import worked, but you still use `serial.Serial(...)` instead of `Serial(...)` later

Comment: There is no serial variable and when i do print(serial) it displays "<module 'serial' from 'C:\\Users\\ryanc\\Documents\\Python\\TestEnv\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\serial\\__init__.py'>"

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt when doing the dir(serial) it did display a long list of functions so it is importing correctly if i am not mistaken

Comment: Okay, what about the other comment? When you import the `Serial` class with `from serial import Serial`, do you change every occurrence of `serial.Serial` into `Serial`?

Comment: @kalehmann i have just tried that when i do it give the error 'ImportError: cannot import name 'Serial' from 'serial' (C:\Users\ryanc\Documents\Python\TestEnv\venv\lib\site-packages\serial\__init__.py)'

Comment: My last suggestion is that you still somehow have the wrong `serial` module. What is the output of `print(serial.__dict__)`?

Comment: This is the output of that command --- {'__name__': 'serial', '__doc__': None, '__package__': 'serial', '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader object at 0x03740930>, '__spec__': ModuleSpec(name='serial', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader object at 0x03740930>, submodule_search_locations=_NamespacePath(['C:\\Users\\ryanc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\serial'])), '__file__': None, '__path__': _NamespacePath(['C:\\Users\\ryanc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\serial'])}

Comment: I am sorry, that was not what I expected. Does `pip3 list | grep serial` gives you only `pyserial`?

Comment: I am not sure what 'grep' is however I did not run when done it grep serial it gave a list of the modules curses, future, iso8601, pip, pyserial, PyYAML, setuptools

Comment: This looks fine. Are you using something like `pyenv`? Try `where python3` and `where pip3`. Maybe you are not using the package provided by pip.

Comment: I am not using pyenv and where should I use the where commands

Comment: The where commands should be entered in cmd.exe.
The output you have provided shows different paths for the serial module.(C:\\Users\\ryanc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\serial and C:\\Users\\ryanc\\Documents\\Python\\TestEnv\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\serial\)

Comment: the second one was using the console via PyCharm

Comment: Have you verified, that your code does not work with both paths?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html and check that PyCharm uses the correct `serial` package

Comment: PyCharm uses the same packages that I previously stated curses, future, iso8601, pip, pyserial, PyYAML, setuptools and the code does give the same error in both locations

Comment: I am sorry, but I have no ideas left. Please let us know, when you figured it out.

Comment: Thank you so much for being this patient and i will update you when i figure it out

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you have installed [the serial package](https://pypi.org/project/serial/) *serializing/deserializing JSON/YAML/XML into python class instances and vice versa* and not the [pySerial package](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/) for accessing the serial port?

Try to uninstall the `serial` package and install the `pyserial`  package instead:

```
pip uninstall serial
pip install pyserial
```

Also make sure your file is not called `serial.py`. In that case `import serial` would just import your own file.

Comment: I have done that, pyserial was already installed. would the import at the top need to be changed to pyserial?

Comment: No. Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.7.0, no other version installed

Comment: Okay, I have the same and it works for me. Your file is not named `serial.py` by any chance?

Comment: No it is not. It seems not to cause any problems when you run it normally however when I call the class that is when the error happens

Comment: Indeed weird. Can you please provide the full code of the method in which you try to instanciate `serial.Serial`?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue, and for me it had to do with importing serial over pyserial before trying anything in the first place. To remedy, I had to perform the following:

```
pip uninstall serial
pip uninstall pyserial
pip install pyserial
```

After that it worked like a charm.